# Как возможно доказать биективность (0;1] и [0; inf) * [0; inf)?

Tags: математика

В материал к заданиям предоставили свойства **"Декартового произведения"**. Но после его применения получилось множество с бесконечностью в квадрате. Выходит, что эти множества не биективны.

**В чём я ошибаюсь или на что стоит обратить внимание?**

Comment: Биективны. Вообще, R1 и R2 биективны друг другу, если вспомнить, что биективность не требует непрерывности. Можно рассмотреть действительные числа как "бесконечную последовательность цифр", и смешать цифры двух последовательностей в одну (беря цифры поочередно из каждой из последовательностей). Получим взаимно-однозначное отображение R2->R1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рассмотрим функцию (1-x)/x

Для каждого x из (0,1] она дает значение в указанном диапазоне [0, inf)

Итак, мы установили биекцию для (0,1] <-> [0,inf)

Пусть теперь у нас есть число из (0,1]. Запишем его в любой системе счисления :) (1 запишем как 0.99999...), и построим два числа, первое из которых будет состоять из цифр на нечетных местах, а второе - на четных. Например, для 0.2718281828459045... это будет числа 0.21212494... и 0.78888505... Каждое из этих чисел лежит в том же диапазоне (0,1], так что имеем биекцию одного числа через построение двух на [0,inf)х[0,inf).

Назад — точно так же. Два числа превращаются в два значения в диапазоне (0,1], и мы собираем их в одно число.

Биекция доказана.

Оба множества имеют мощность континуума, так что они обязательно биективны.

Вот вам простенькая задачка — есть бесконечная гостиница с бесконечным числом номеров, и все заняты. И тут приезжает бесконечное число постояльцев. Как их разместить? Легко: дать команду "каждый постоялец из номера n переезжает в номер 2n.

Но ничуть не сложнее, если приедет бесконечно много автобусов, в каждом из которых будет бесконечно много гостей — подумайте сами, как их разместить.